# unable to execute sql query in pentaho report designer

Tags: pentaho-report-designer

We are using Pentaho, I have configured SQL DB and details in Pentaho, after that I am trying to execute that query. But once we publish the report, we are getting **"Failed at query"** error.

What is the reason for that error? We have kept SQL, MySQL, JDBC jar files in the correct path, *pentaho/report-designer/lib*.

Please let me know the solution.

Comment: Can you post a log?

Comment: which DB you are trying to connect? make sure that you don't have more then one jar file for one database in specific location.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's been a while since this question was asked, but I came up to a similar issue myself. Apparently if the BI-Server version and client versions are not match (especially if the server version is lower) then your reports wont be generated and receive "failed at query" error.

So first make sure client and server has same versions